# "I want that you do" vs. "I want you to do"

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

> 1. I want you to get me an orange.
> 2. I want that you get me an orange.

Which is correct? and What is the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 2):

We do not normally use a *that*-clause with "want". So the second sentence is not grammatical.

Comment: I am not convinced that the second one is ungrammatical, would you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: @Cardinal I tried to find an instance in COCA but there isn't any. Most instances are just concealed passive constructions such as "I want that person arrested". I don't think I have anything more to explain. The verb "want" just doesn't govern a that-clause as an argument.

Comment: It may be grammatical, but it is definitely not idiomatic English.

Comment: I agree with the other comments. The second sentence is grammatical (syntactically sound)—and, therefore, it's "correct" in a strict sense. However, it's not idiomatic and wouldn't normally be used. The following is also a grammatical (and syntactically sound) sentence, even though it wouldn't normally be used: *Colourless green ideas sleep furiously.* You should qualify your statement so it doesn't lead to the wrong impression.

Comment: @Jason "Tell" and "say" are synonyms. "Tell" take a direct object and a that-clause: eg. "She told me she was there". But "She said me she was there" isn't grammatical. That's because the verb "say" and "tell" don't have the same argumentation. Every verb has its own unique argumentation and that's all I can say. I can't think of a situation where it is grammatical to use "want" with a that-clause.

Comment: "Colourless green ideas sleep furiously" is syntactically sound because the argumention is fine. Now change the verb "sleep" with "make". It is no longer grammatical and is still nonsensical. The second sentence is just as bad as *"She said me to go there" (cf. "She told me to go there".) Some verbs can freely take a that-clause, but some verbs don't. Some verbs also freely take a to-infinitival clause, and some don't.

Comment: Yep. The verb in question simply does not have that pattern of complementation; it doesn't license a clause of that type. The sentence as a whole is therefore ungrammatical.

Comment: Why do some posters make what is so obvious into such a big thing? This answer is right and in English: I want that [clause] **is not grammatical** in any of the language's varieties,dialects, etc. etc. etc.